# internally by the HashMap to check if two keys are equal or not which algorithm is being used?

Tags: java, hashmap

hashcode() method generate hashcode of a object, which helps in identifying exact bucket/index.
lets say at this bucket(index) there are already few key-value pairs present then the key which will being inserted should be compared with all the present keys.
Which algorithm being used to search the keys here?

Comment: Well, the implementation is open source, so look into the source, e.g. [http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java]

Comment: Link doesn't work.

Comment: It just compares Node objects.
This line:  http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l305

Comment: It's not an algorithm, it's a hook: `key1.equals(key2)`. `equals` method is implemented by the key objects themselves.

Answer (score 1):

It will perform a linear search over `HashMap`'s entry set. It will get the entry set by seeing your `key` (by `hash`) and then iterate over the entry set(Your multiple key-value pairs/pair) one by one and check the right key for you.

Here is the implementation

```
public V get(Object key) {

    if (key == null)
        return getForNullKey();
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());

    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];e != null;e = e.next) {
         Object k;
         if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
             return e.value;
         }
     }
     return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i remember my teacher correctly;

Javas `HashMap<K,V>` uses `hashcode` (inherited from `Object`, and preferably overridden by your key) as you say, to locate where in the underlying structure it should store your key-value pair.

If several `<K,V>` pairs are present at the same location, a call to `get(K k)` would use your keys `boolean equals(Object o)` method to figure out which one you want (also inherited by `Object`), or a call to `put` would use the same technique to figure out which value to replace with your new one.

It will first however check the references. If your key and the one store in the hasmap is the *same*, it will not perform the check using `equals`.